# Glob pattern excluding some of the first level directories

Tags: glob, grunt-contrib-concat

I have a folder structure like this

ProjectX
   .......|_____node_modules
   .......|_____src
  .......|_____build
   .......|_____app
   .......|_____libraries

I have written a glob pattern in grunt browserify something like this

src:['**/*.js','!node_modules','!build'],
dest:'build/build.js'

What i want from above code is, all .js files in my project should be browserified except the .js files in 'node_modules' and 'build' folder.

But what actually is happening is still the files from node_modules and build folder are browserified in my 'build/build.js' destination.

And i do not want to specify  folder names of the .js file i require. I do not want to do something like this

['src/**/*.js' ... etc]

How can i solve this problem?